# Unable to get child index in Unity

Tags: unity

I'm trying to create a infinite racing game. I have a RoadSystem game object that instantiates a slab of road. On awake about 8 slabs are created. I'm trying to create a system where once the car passes the second or the third slab, the first slab is destroyed and then a new one is added at the end. I'm unable to get the index of the slabs. This is the code I have attached to a trigger which is just an empty gameobject with a box collider attached:

```
public class AddRemoveRoadSlab : MonoBehaviour {

  Public Road road

  private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
   {
      if (other.gameObject.tag == "RoadSlab"){
      Debug.Log(road.GetComponent<Transform>().GetSiblingIndex());
   } 
}
```

What the debug.log statement is printing is the index of the Road gameobject in the Hierarchy that includes the camera, direction light etc. I want to get the index of the children of the Road gameobject.
Can someone please help?

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of how the Road and slab are configured. The road script generates the slabs. The slabs are just unity plane objects.

[image: Screenshot1]

Comment: Can you show us how the Road and Slab objects are configured in the Inspector? Presumably you tried outputting the index of the collider passed as the `other` argument?

Comment: I have added the screenshot. I would like to get the index of the 2nd or 3rd slab that is generated. But not able to get the index of the slabs. What I get is the index of the road gameobject in the hierarchy in this case I get 3. If I move the road game object to the bottom, then the index becomes 4. I want to be able to get the index of the slabs that get instantiated under the road gameobject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you meant to write this:

```cs
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
    if (other.CompareTag("RoadSlab")) {
       Debug.Log(other.transform.GetSiblingIndex());
    }
}
```

You want the index of whichever collider you're interacting with, not the single road stored in your member variable.

Comment: thanks a lot for this....its working fine now...